# Select on External table running very very slow on Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance, external-tables

We have external table created, we need to run select on the table and select all the records, the select runs very very slow. Its not completing even after 30 mins, the table contains around 2millon recs

We also need to query this table from another DB and even this runs very very slow, doesn't return even after 30 mins.

Select is of the form:

select col1, col2,...col3 from ext_table;

Need help in: 
1. Any suggestions on reducing the time taken for execution?

Note: we need to select entire content of the table so where condition might not be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the WHERE clause to push parameters to the remote database, then there is no way to optimize the performance of the query. You are returning the whole table.

My suggestion is to use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) to have a local copy of the table on this SQL Database that synchronizes with the remote Azure SQL Database at X interval of time.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, will check your suggestion about Data sync.